# How to add an array from the data attribute and id using javascript and combine them in array php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I just want to ask if how to merge this two array from all id value and data-rate value on my list order? there is too many ul li, so i need to get them all and store it into array.

this is my code in javascript:

```
                var h = [];

                $("ul.reorder-photos-list li").each(function() {  h.push($(this).attr('id').substr(9));  });

                var x = [];

                $("ul.reorder-photos-list li").each(function() {  x.push($(this).attr('data-rate').substr(9));  });


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "order_update.php",
                    data: {
                        ids: " " + h + "",
                        rate: " " + x + ""
                        },
                    success: function(html) 
                    {
                        window.location.reload();
                        /*$("#reorder-helper").html( "Reorder Completed - Image reorder have been successfully completed. Please reload the page for testing the reorder." ).removeClass('light_box').addClass('notice notice_success');
                        $('.reorder_link').html('reorder photos');
                        $('.reorder_link').attr("id","");*/
                    }
                });
```

and this is my html code:

```
<li id="image_li_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="ui-sortable-handle">
<input id="rate" type="text" value="<?= $row['rate']?>" data-rate="<?php echo $row['rate']; ?>" >
```

and then in my order_update.php this is my code.

```
$idArray    = explode(",",$_POST['ids']);
$rateArray  = explode(",",$_POST['rate']);

$ids = array();
foreach ($idArray as $id) {
    $ids[] = $id;
}

$rates = array();
foreach ($rateArray as $rate) {
    $rates[] = $rate;
}

$n = 0;
$orderArray = array();
while( $n <= count($idArray) )
{
    $orderArray[] = array("id" => $ids[$n], "data" => $rates[$n]);
    $n++;
}
```

and this is my insert query from orderArray

```
function updateOrder($orderArray){
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($orderArray as $array){
            $update = mysqli_query($this->connect,"UPDATE `test` SET `order` = $count, `rate`=$array[rate] WHERE id = $array[id]");
            $count ++;  
        }
        return true;
    }
```

hope someones helps me. :)thanks in advance!

Comment: Please simplify you code.

Comment: h is an array not a comma separated string, right? Same with x.  So what would `ids: " " + h + "", rate: " " + x + ""` be printing?

Comment: actually i exploded it from comma and make it array. i want to combine the rateArray into the id array which is multidimensional array. @developerwjk

Comment: wrong. I'm talking about on the javascript side. your php code is irrelevant because your ajax is not going to send what you think it is.

Comment: oh yes its not a comma separated string. they getting those value in id and data-rate from the ul li html

Comment: @developerwjk i see, can you guide me? im not that good at javascript.

Comment: @developerwjk i just want to store in multidimensional array this id value and data-rate attribute. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up your data, you don't need to have multiple loops. You can loop through the data once:

```
var dataArray = [];

$("ul.reorder-photos-list li").each(function() {  
    var el = $(this),
        input = el.children(':input'); // This gets the input decendent of the li

    // When adding one item at a time to an array, array[array.length] = item is better
    dataArray[dataArray.length] = {
        id: el.attr('id').substr(9),
        rate: input.val(),
    };
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "order_update.php",
    data: { items: dataArray }, // items gives the PHP something to use as a key in the POST data
    success: function(html) {...}
});
```

Your PHP will look like this:

```
// The data passed from the Ajax call is already an array
$itemsArray    = $_POST['items'];

// Your function to process the array
function updateOrder($orderArray) {
    foreach ($orderArray as $index => $array) {
        // $index will already have a count, you need to +1 because it's 0-based
        mysqli_query($this->connect, "UPDATE `test` SET `order` = " . ($index + 1) . ", `rate`=" . $array['rate'] . " WHERE id = " . $array['id']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: so sorry for the late reply, i just forgot the rate must be in input value. hehehe. not in the same html element.

`<input class="reorder-rate" type="text" value="<?= $row['rate']?>"`

is this correct? `$("input.reorder-rate").each(function() {  h.push($(this).attr('value').substr(9));  });`

Comment: I forget if jquery automatically converts JS objects to strings before AJAX-ing them elsewhere. I typically use vanilla JavaScript since I mostly work on small projects that don't require expansive libraries. It also helps to have a more in-depth understanding of the base language and it's capabilities.

Comment: @CSS this answer is the closest answer i am looking for. what is only need to change here is `rate: el.attr('data-rate').substr(9),` make it to input value. any ideas mate?

Comment: @xerwudjohn, I've updated the code in my answer to get the rate from an input.

Comment: @Jeffwa Hi mate, im having on the database problem. i think the rate is value is not saving. but the id array is good.

Comment: @Jeffwa pls help me. i think the input didnt catch any value in array. thats why its not saving to database.

Answer (score 1):

```
var rates;
$("ul.reorder-photos-list li").each(function() {
     rates.id.push($(this).attr('id').substr(9));
     rates.rate.push($(this).attr('data-rate').substr(9));
});
```

This will create your JSON object of h/x pairs.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    , url: "order_update.php"
    , data: { JSON.stringify(rates); }
    , success: function(html) {
        window.location.reload();
        /* $("#reorder-helper").html(
         * "Reorder Completed - Image reorder have been successfully completed.
         * Please reload the page for testing the reorder." 
         * ).removeClass('light_box').addClass('notice notice_success');
         * $('.reorder_link').html('reorder photos');
         * $('.reorder_link').attr("id","");
         */
    }
});
```

This should fix your call to send the correct data.

Your PHP side is going to want to have something similar to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['rates'])) {
    $ratesString = $_POST['rates'];
    $rates = json_decode($ratesString);
}
// Do other things with $hx`
```

Your insert query is off, too. You need to declare each value as a variable or your compiler is going to hate your PHP, too. You also have some unnecessary quotes in your query.

```
function updateOrder($orderArray){
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($orderArray as $array){
        $rate = $array['rate'];
        $id = $array['id'];
        mysqli_query($this->connect,"UPDATE test SET order = $count, rate = '$rate' WHERE id = '$id'");
        $count ++;  
    }
    return true;
}
```

For your HTML, I think this is what you were going for, but not sure since it's not really explained all that well...Feel free to comment on your intentions.

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($orderArray as $array) : ?>
<li id="image_li_<?php echo $array['id']; ?>" class="ui-sortable-handle">
<input id="rate" type="text" value="<?php echo $array['rate']?>" data-rate="<?php echo $array['rate']; ?>" ></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

-C§

Comment: @xerwudjohn Does this fix the HTML portion? If no, give some more hints =D

Comment: Your code is too complicated hehe. its a bit hard. lol but thanks for your help. just want to ask do you have any idea on how to get all values in input value? this is my code `$("input.data-rate").each(function() {  x.push($(this).attr('value').substr(9));  });` the input class name is data-rate

Comment: @xerwudjohn The first block in my response does that...it creates a js object `rates` with attributes `rate` and `id`. You can access the attributes by using `rates.rate` or `rates.id`. The js object will print out something like this if you use a `console.log(rates);`: `{rates: [ {id: 0, rate: 2%}, {id: 1, rate: 2.2%}, ... ]`. And this code is as simple as I could think to do it for now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the code now. thanks for your help guys!

```
                var h = [];

                $("ul.reorder-photos-list li").each(function() {  h.push($(this).attr('id').substr(9));  });

                var x = [];

                $("input").each(function() {  x.push($(this).val());  });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "order_update.php",
                    data: {ids: " " + h + "",rate: " " + x + ""},
                    /*data: { items: dataArray },*/
                    success: function(html) 
                    {
                     ...
                    }

                });
```

In Php side:

```
$idArray    = explode(",",$_POST['ids']);
$rateArray  = explode(",",$_POST['rate']);

$ids = array();
foreach ($idArray as $id) {
    $ids[] = $id;
}

$rates = array();
foreach ($rateArray as $rate) {
    $rates[] = $rate;
}

$n = 0;
$orderArray = array();
while( $n <= count($idArray) )
{
    $orderArray[] = array("id" => $ids[$n] , "rate" => $rates[$n]);
    $n++;
}

$db->updateOrder($orderArray);

function updateOrder($orderArray){
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($orderArray as $array){
            mysqli_query($this->connect, "UPDATE `test` SET `morder` = " . $count . ", `mtoursrate`=" . $array['rate'] . " WHERE id = " . $array['id']);
            $count ++;  
        }
        return true;
    }
```